# Awk equivalent of MySQL's substring_index

Tags: awk

I have strings with delimited fields, but a different number of fields in each, eg:

- this/that
- this/that/theother
- this/that/theother/stuff

I want to retrieve the last two fields in each case, ie:

- this/that
- that/theother
- theother/stuff

This is easy in MySQL with the substring_index function, and I see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885793/php-equivalent-of-mysqls-function-substring-index) explains how to do it in PHP.

Can someone help me achieve the same with awk in the command line? Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason for awk? `sed "s,.*/\([^/]*/[^/]*\),\\1,"`

Comment: Or the shorter GNU sed variation: `sed -r 's,.*/([^/]*/){2},\1,'`

Comment: No, only that I've found awk helpful before - thanks, sed is great too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo 'this/that/theother/stuff' | awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1) "/" $(NF)}'
```